# In iOS , Why will viewWithTag method return nil?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard

#### Today, I met a very strange thing.

I have a tableview which is built by Storyboard.
the type of the tableview is ***Static and Grouped***
In one of its Cell , I have a cell with a switch(which is set ***ON*** in Storyboard).
I set the switch's tag to 10000816 by Storyboard.

I try to use [self.tableview viewWithTag 10000816] to get the switch in the tableview's controller. Failed.

OK. I then try to get the Cell first and try [cell viewWithTag] and somehow, it succeed.

Then I wonder why.
So I just left the following line uncommented.

```
UITableViewCell* cell =  [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
```

Following by

```
UISwitch* switchButton = [self.tableView viewWithTag: 10000816];
    [switchButton setOn:NO animated:YES];
```

OK , this time , succeed again.
And I comment the Get-Cell line,which I think irrelevant.
then strange thing happened.It failed. The only change I had made is just a irrelevant line.
So strange.

## Question

Why will viewWithTag return nil if I just comment the Get-Cell line?

```
- (void) switchOff{ 
  //****** the line below is the magic Get-Cell  line , if I comment this line , viewWithTag will return nil    
     UITableViewCell* cell =  [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
    

    UISwitch* switchButton = [self.tableView viewWithTag: 10000816];    
    [switchButton setOn:NO animated:YES];  
}
```

[update]
my switchOff is called in - (void)viewDidAppear:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self switchOff]
}
```

Comment: How table looks like? Maybe at the moment you call `viewWithTag` that cell is not yet initialised?

Comment: viewWithTag is called in ViewDidAppear

Comment: Is cell visible at the moment of presenting table?

Comment: @JohnTracid Yes , I don't have to much cell there.

Comment: You need to cal `viewWithTag:` on `cell`, not `self.tableView`.

Comment: Why do you get the first cell in `viewDidAppear`?

Comment: @Bannings this view will show up many times and due to the user's configuration, the the status of the switch need to change. The main reason I get Cell in `viewDidAppear`is that I want to make sure the cell is already been created. It's not important, I just wonder Why this strange thing happen.

Comment: @rmaddy First of all. Isn't that `viewWithTag`will look into its children , and recursively traversal the hierachy tree , using something like Deep-First Search Algorithm to find the first view with the Tag match I passed in. So Since the cell is the children of tableview, on `self.tableview` doesn't matter at all. Second, I just wonder why after I use the `Get-Cell Line` , `viewWithTag` return something rather than nil.

Comment: @rmaddy I don't think so , I call it in `viewDidAppear`

Answer (score 0):

If your tableview is a Prototype one (one whose value will be filled by `cellForRowAtIndexPath`method) then dropping a cell inside the tableview, you wont get to see the cell, as that cell is not being created, so is its content.

If your tableview is a static one, only then will the storyboard content of a cell will be shown and you will get the control inside the cell with that tag.

I think your tableview is a prototype one, and as because the cell isnt being created so your `[self.tableview viewWithTag 10000816]` is returning nil as that control has not been created.

Hope could make you understand

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But is a static one . and the strange thing is, if I uncomment that Get-Cell line, which seems irrelevant, It will successfully  get the Switch, rather than nil.